# Usage mystérieux de « toi-même, tu sais »

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, paroles-de-chanson, pronoms-personnels

Je n'arrive pas a comprendre ce que « toi-même » veut dire dans [ces paroles de chanson](http://www.chartsinfrance.net/Yannick/id-100299512.html) (Yannick, [*Ces Soirées-là*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces_soir%C3%A9es-l%C3%A0)) :

> Ces soirées-là, on drague, on branche,
>   Toi-même, tu sais pourquoi :
>   Pour qu'on finisse ensemble toi et moi.

Je les comprendrais s'ils avaient dit « toi, tu sais pourquoi ». Mais de quoi s'agit-il, le « toi-même » ? De ce mot, je ne comprends que deux sens :

1. Bien que tu l'aies créée toi-même, elle est déjà figée.
2. Tu aimeras ton prochain comme toi-même.

En (1), ça veut dire que toi tu l'as créée, et personne d'autre ne l'a créée.
En (2), ça veut dire que le sujet « tu » et l'objet « toi » de « aimer » sont la même chose.

Je pense qu'il y a un troisième sens caché dans ces paroles. Est-ce que vous pouvez m'expliquer ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A noter qu'il y a une expression qu'on entend parfois, qui est très précisément "toi même tu sais" (parfois abrégé TMTC) (oui, avec un "C", c'est du langage SMS, moi aussi je souffre n'en reparlons plus jamais).

C'est une expression d'origine ouest-africaine, qui correspond à peu près à « comme tu le sais bien » ou « tu le sais aussi bien que moi » en français plus classique. On ne peut pas vraiment dire qu'elle ait pénétré le français standard, elle est quasiment inexistante à l'écrit en dehors de paroles de chanson. C'est le titre d'une [série de vidéos éducatives de l'INPES](http://www.inpes.sante.fr/CFESBases/catalogue/detaildoc.asp?numfiche=1203), mais c'est justement une série destinée aux populations originaires d'Afrique subsaharienne.

Voir une tentative d'explication sur [cette page](http://dictionnaire-urbain.fr/?p=535), mais par définition ce genre d'expression très volatile et éphémère ne se retrouve pas dans les références "officielles".

Comment: merci ! J'aimais toutes les réponses.

Comment: Pour faire simple : "Moi-même: forme renforcée de moi." et donc "toi-même" n'est qu'une fioriture pour renforcer le "toi", dans cette forme d'utilisation. De plus je pense fortement que cet "ajout" est la aussi probablement uniquement pour le rythme du refrain.

Answer (score 4):

On peut essayer d'éclairer le sens en enlevant le *-même*  :

> Ces soirées là: on drague, on branche,
>  toi*[-même], tu sais pour quoi :
>  ...

C'est un usage courant, surtout chez les jeunes, de dire *toi-même* dans une discussion. On rajoute le *-même* pour insister sur le *toi*.

Cette chanson utilise les formulations de l'oralité pour être mieux être entendue du public ciblé.

Il peut aussi servir de réponse à une insulte ou à une invective :

> — Tu n'es qu'un imbécile !
>
> — *Toi-même* !
>
> — ...

***Édit'***

Il y a aussi un sens personnel :

> — Toi *[la personne que tout le monde connais, ton visage social ]*, tu sais pourquoi …
>
> — Toi-même *[la personne que tes proches connaissent, ton être intime ]*, tu sais pourquoi …

Answer (score -5):

Je crois qu'en ce cas c'est une contraction de `sois toi-même`, abrévié `toi-même`.